# Matrix Multiplication with Object Arrays in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multiplication

I am wondering how matrix multiplication can be supported in numpy with arrays of `dtype=object`. I have homomorphically encrypted numbers that are encapsulated in a class `Ciphertext` for which I have overriden the basic math operators like `__add__`, `__mul__` etc.

I have created numpy array where each entry is an instance of my class `Ciphertext` and numpy understands how to broadcast addition and multiplication operations just fine.

```
    encryptedInput = builder.encrypt_as_array(np.array([6,7])) # type(encryptedInput) is <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
    encryptedOutput = encryptedInput + encryptedInput
    builder.decrypt(encryptedOutput)                           # Result: np.array([12,14])
```

However, numpy won't let me do matrix multiplications

```
out = encryptedInput @ encryptedInput # TypeError: Object arrays are not currently supported
```

I don't quite understand why this happens considering that addition and multiplication works. I guess it has something to do with numpy not being able to know the shape of the object, since it could be a list or something fance.

**Naive Solution**: I could write my own class that extends `ndarray` and overwrite the `__matmul__` operation, but I would probably lose out on performance and also this approach entails implementing broadcasting etc., so I would basically reinvent the wheel for something that should work as it is right now.

**Question**: How can I use the standard matrix multiplication provided by numpy on arrays with `dtype=objects` where the objects behave exactly like numbers?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't think you can; numpy's dot and tensordot functions are optimised for scalar, numeric dtypes, not objects.

Comment: I just figured out that it works using tensordot.. Correct result:
out = np.tensordot(encryptedInput, encryptedInput, axes=([1,0]))

Comment: Hah, interesting. Feel free to self-answer your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For whatever reason matmul doesn't work, but the tensordot function works as expected.

```
encryptedInput = builder.encrypt_as_array(np.array([6,7]))
out = np.tensordot(encryptedInput, encryptedInput, axes=([1,0])) 
    # Correct Result: [[ 92. 105.]
    #                  [120. 137.]]
```

Now it's just a hassle to adjust the axes. I still wonder whether this is actually faster than a naive implementation with for loops.

Comment: I'm not following you handling of shapes.  Your plus example suggests you expect: (2,)+(2,)=>(2,).  But a numeric (2,)@(2,)=>scalar, same as `np.dot` with 2 1d arrays.  That `tensordot` expression requires that the first array be 2d.

Answer (score 1):

`tensordot` has an extended example using `object` dtype and string concatenation.  It's actually using `np.dot` for this:

```
In [89]: np.dot(np.array([['a'],['b']],object),np.array([[2,3]]))
Out[89]: 
array([['aa', 'aaa'],
       ['bb', 'bbb']], dtype=object)
```

This example is small, but it does suggest that the `object` version is taking a slower route (than the equivalent numeric one):

```
In [98]: timeit np.dot(np.array([[1],[2]]),np.array([[2,3]]))
7.3 µs ± 20.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
In [99]: timeit np.dot(np.array([[1],[2]],object),np.array([[2,3]]))
12 µs ± 121 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

`np.dot` code is compiled, so it'll take more work to verify the difference.

For 1 and 2d arrays, `np.dot` is just as good as `np.matmul`.  `matmul` was introduced for the `@` operator convenience, and for its extension to 3d and higher.  Previously that 3d+ behavior could only be achieved with `einsum` or with iteration on the upper dimensions.

`matmul` for 2 3d arrays is effectively:

```
 for i in range(a.shape[0]):
     data[i,:,:] = a[i,:,:].dot(b[i,:,:])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ndarray.dot` method, which apparently works for `np.object` dtypes even when the `@` operator fails:

```
out = encryptedInput.dot(encryptedInput)
```